# remove handler of a sub with additional arguments

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework, addressof

I try to remove an handler regarding a sub that contains an additional argument, but it doesn't work and it generates a warning :
"The 'AddressOf' expression has no effect in this context because the method argument to 'AddressOf' requires a relaxed conversion to the delegate type of the event. Assign the 'AddressOf' expression to a variable, and use the variable to add or remove the method as the handler.
Here is my sub :

```
Private Sub ComboBox_MFC_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs, Optional ByVal SingleCase As Int16 = -1) Handles ComboBox_MFC.SelectedValueChanged
...
End Sub
```

Here is my initial code to remove this handler:

```
Private Sub Me_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ...
        RemoveHandler ComboBox_MFC.SelectedValueChanged, AddressOf ComboBox_MFC_SelectedValueChanged
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MyDataSet1.MFC' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.MFCTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MyDataSet1.MFC)
        ComboBox_MFC.DataSource = New DataView(Me.MyDataSet1.MFC, "IsPresent = True", "Name", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
        ComboBox_MFC.ValueMember = "Name"
        ComboBox_MFC.DisplayMember = "Name"
        ...
        AddHandler ComboBox_MFC.SelectedValueChanged, AddressOf ComboBox_MFC_SelectedValueChanged
        ...
End Sub
```

Unfortunately the handler is not removed properly and the execution pass through my sub when combobox is filled.

So I've done what message advised to do and I've used a variable to assign the addressOf expression. 
Here is what I've tried :

```
Private Sub Me_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ...
        Dim ComboboxesEventAddress As New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBoxes_SelectedValueChanged)
        RemoveHandler ComboBox_MFC.SelectedValueChanged, ComboboxesEventAddress
        ...
        AddHandler ComboBox_MFC.SelectedValueChanged, ComboboxesEventAddress
End Sub
```

Warning message disapears but issue remains.
PS: I use Compact Framework

Comment: Seems like you've got the same problem; [GeeksWithBlogs](http://geekswithblogs.net/TechnicalDebtor/archive/2010/05/04/removehandler-issues-with-custom-events.aspx)

Comment: That is not the correct way to implement a custom event.  Events ought to all conform to `(Sender, e)` format.  To add an argument create a new class which inherits from `EventArgs` and add your variable.  Depending on what you are doing, the event itself might need to have a different name since there is already a standard cbo event with a different sig.

Comment: Instead of `SelectedValueChanged` use event `SelectionChangesCommitted`. `SelectionChangesCommitted` event will not firing when you change selected value programmatically, only when user do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you actually remove the handler that you wanted. I mean, sometimes people do that

```
RemoveHandler ComboBox_MFC.SelectedIndexChanged, ComboboxesEventAddress
...
AddHandler ComboBox_MFC.SelectedValueChanged, ComboboxesEventAddress
```

where the remove the `SelectedIndexChanged` instead of the `SelectedValueChanged` ;-)